# is there a way to authenticate user role in firebase storage rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am trying to restrict firebase storage based on user role.

```
Database:
    users
        <uid>
            admin=false
            ... ... ...
```

I am trying to use the following kind of rule in firebase storage:

```
root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('user').child('admin').val() == true
```

I am getting access denied after adding this to the write rule.

Thanks.

Comment: The Firebase Storage security rules cannot refer to data in the Database. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188459/create-group-access-to-firebase-storage-without-using-custom-authorization) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157858/firebase-storage-whats-the-proper-rules-for-user-based-uploading-deleting) for ways to do something like role-based security.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Its a little hacky, but I guess thats all I can do for now.

Comment: You can use "custom claims", you have to set the custom claims in one of your Firebase Functions, but they'll be passed to Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Frank van Puffelen pointed out in his comment:

```
function isAdminUser() {
    return request.auth.uid in {
        "yaddayadddayaddUserIDKey":"User Name1"
    };
}

service firebase.storage {
    match /b/<appName>.appspot.com/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read;
            allow write: if request.auth != null && isAdminUser();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: The is admin function seems to be hardcoded values. Is this currently the only option?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all there is for now.