# Firebase Storage: Role based rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to only allow some users upload files to a certain folder on Firebase Storage.

The role of the users can be found in the database, any idea how I could access that in the Firebase Storage rules (by only using Firebase).

I know you can check whether a user is logged in or not, but there has to be a way to dig deeper, right?

Kind regards
Bram

Comment: *firebaser here* There is currently no way to access the Firebase Database from with Firebase Storage security rules. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187424/is-there-a-way-to-authenticate-user-role-in-firebase-storage-rules

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank, I was looking for a "Non Hardcode" kinda way. Do you know if there are any plans to add this in the future?

Comment: We know that many developers would benefit from having a more controllable way to set role-based permissions. But nobody is working on such a feature at the moment, so having the UIDs in the rules is your best bet.