# firestore.get function not working in Cloud Storage security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

I want to investigate that the user is admin or not but this is not working.

I get an error:

> You don't have a permission to acces the object

```js
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {

      match /articles/{allPaths=**} {
        allow read;
        allow create: if firestore.get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
        allow update;
    }
  }
}
```

I try to rewrite the code, but this is not working too:

```js
allow create: if firestore.get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).isAdmin == true;
```

Answer (score 1):

> According to this [Firebase blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules) Security Rules in Cloud Storage for Firebase now supports cross-service Rules with two brand new functions `firestore.get()` and `firestore.exists()`. Your rule should be

```
allow create: if firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
```

instead of

```
allow create: if firestore.get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
```

> This feature allows you to read only the Firestore data belonging to the same Firebase project as your Cloud Storage; you will not be able to query Firestore data from a different project.

Firebase currently supports only 1 database instance per project so the name must be `(default)` in path. A similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887203/20239914) explains this.

I have also recreated the issue at my end and it turns out this feature is only available to `(default)` databases.

Comment: I'm getting an error telling me that it does not know about `.data`. Did you every encounter that?