# How to enabling cross-service communication in Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

In my fireaase storage i have a rule that allows access if

```
request.auth.token.email in firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/Groups/$(groupId)).data.owners
```

This rule works great in my dev-environment, but when i test in my test-environment

```
firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/Groups/$(groupId))
```

becomes null and i get "access denied"

In all the guides it says that you have to "Enable cross-service communication" and that the first time you save the rules using firestore.get, you should get a popup asking for "Provision cross-service rules"

The problem is that the first time i saved the rules with the firestore.get, i did not get the pop-up question. And nowhere I can find does it says **how** to attach that permission, it just says I should!

It's probably something so easy that I haven't found it, but please help!

I have read and tried:

- https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules
- [Can Firebase Cloud Storage rules validate against Firestore data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861983/can-firebase-cloud-storage-rules-validate-against-firestore-data)
- https://makerkit.dev/blog/tutorials/firestore-storage-rules#enabling-cross-service-communication

Comment: Firebaser here! It's possible to check if the permission is set up correctly. First, navigate to the [Cloud Console IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) for your project. Check the checkbox titled "Include Google-provided role grants." Look for a service account ending in `@gcp-sa-firebasestorage.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. This service account should have `Firebase Rules Firestore Service Agent` listed under the "Role" column.

Comment: Thank you so much @SamOlsen! It worked, cant understand why I did not get the popup the first time...

You should have made a regular answer so I could mark it as correct! But thanks anyway!